# Android, NumberPicker setOnClickListener

Tags: android, uitableview, android-custom-view, numberpicker

When deveolping with cocoa for iOS, i was able to alter `UIPickerView` by using `UITableViewCell` as the `viewForRow`. This enabled the `UIPickerView` to utilize `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` (as seen below)
[image: iOS: UIPickerView]

[image: iOS: UIPickerView2]

I am trying to recreate this in Android, however i'm running into issues surrounding the `NumberPicker`. I read that `NumberPicker` uses the click event, with `setClickable` to react however the result isn't sufficient for my intended purpose.

What i wish for is the user to click on the center highlighted row of the `NumberPicker`, which will call an `onClick()` function. Here, the ImageView of the row will be updated to show a checkmark image, thus the user is notified that this row has been 'selected'. The view of the row would be something like this:

**Row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="8" />
   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`(ImageView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE / VIEW.VISIBLE)` would be used to hide or show the check mark.

**My Question**, how would one register an `onClick` event of a `NumberPicker`?
One idea i'm attempting is to set a listener over the area of the screen where the NumberPicker's selected value would appear. however this feels very hacky & i would feel more confident for the click event to register on the actual UI element itself.

**Update**

It would seem that `onClickListener` does not work with number picker anymore. All that happens is the TextView of the row is selected with a keyboard displayed.